# .NET link - index of property

Tags: .netlink, iterators, data-types

I have a property in .NET Type, which is actually a generic list of objects. When I try access the property using numeric index e.g. 10, this works. However when I iterate through indices using indexer such as i, then I get error "NET::nofield: No public field or property named i exists for the .NET type ..."

How to resolve this?

Comment: Could you please share your Mathematica code that is causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I need to use Item indexer, but item index starts from 0, not 1:

If you write a class in C# and give it an indexer, the compiler creates a public property named Item for you. This is a parameterized property, meaning that it takes an argument like a method call. The indexer syntax is just a shorthand for calling the Item property.

See

[Calling .NET from the Wolfram Language: Indexers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromTheWolframLanguage.html#24524)

Comment: It would be great if you could add some simple example code to this answer. It will make it more useful for anyone else facing the same problem who finds this Q&A.

Comment: i added more details and direct link